# Azure Bot Returning "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)" error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

We have created bot solution and published it in Azure.
It was working fine locally.
In Azure we are protecting the web app bot with another App service resource.
Due to this we are getting "Failed to load resource:the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)" error.

In the app service, under Authentication/Authorization tab, for "Action to take when request is not authenticated" dropdown if i select "Allow Anonymous request" option bot is working fine. If i select "Login with Azure Active directory" bot is not working.

Bot is not working even in Test in WebChat in azure site itself.

We are able to access bot default page after providing credentials.

Please let me know what is the step i am missing and let me know if you need any other information.

Code to connect bot.

```
    BotChat.App({
        botConnection: botConnection,
        user: { id: model.userId, Username: model.LoginUser},
        bot: { id: model.botId, name: model.botName },
        resize: 'window',
        speechOptions: speechOptions,
        locale: 'en',
        sendTypingIndicator: true
    }, document.getElementById('BotChatElement'));

    botConnection
        .postActivity({
            from: user,
            name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
            type: 'event',
            value: ''
        })
        .subscribe(function (id) {
            console.log('"trigger requestWelcomeDialog" sent');
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [built-in authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) in Azure app service is not suitable here.

You should follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cbot-oauth) to add authentication to your bot.

Note: The **redirect url** should be `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) is an sample which uses bot authentication capabilities in Azure Bot service.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Let me check this option.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. It is in progress. Will update you soon.

Comment: Hi Tony, I am still facing the same issue, i have created separated solution.
Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication

But still facing same issue.

Comment: @SriramTamilarasan Have you followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cbot-oauth?

Comment: @SriramTamilarasan Did you test it with  Bot Framework Emulator?

Comment: @SriramTamilarasan My pleasure. I have tested this sample several days ago and it works fine with the Emulator.

Comment: I have tested in Emulator and working fine, but still in Azure as we are protecting the web app bot with another App service resource we are getting same error when sending message.
In the app service, under Authentication/Authorization tab, for "Action to take when request is not authenticated" dropdown if i select "Allow Anonymous request" option bot is working fine. If i select "Login with Azure Active directory" bot is not working.

Comment: @SriramTamilarasan Oh, easy auth is not needed here. Just like I mentioned in the answer.